# how does delete function work with ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, crud

I am doing a simple school database project as homework.  I am learning CRUD and in the meantime, trying to apply on my project. But the issue is the `delete` button is not functioning.

I am not too sure what I am doing wrong. I will appreciate your help. Thanks A lot.

My code so far is:

**HTML**

```
                    <div class="row">

                        <form method="post" id="add-lecture-form" class="col-xs-6 ajax-form" action="Controller/CourseController.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="create">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="add a lecture">
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <div class="col-xs-6">  </div>

                            <div id="lecture-result"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function getList() {

            var data = {'action': 'getList'};
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Controller/CourseController.php',
                data: data, // action = getList muss dem Controller ,
                type: 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#lecture-result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        getList();


        $('#add-lecture-form').off('submit');
        $('#add-lecture-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var postData = $(this).serialize();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var type = $(this).attr('method');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: postData,
                type: type,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#lecture-result").html(data);
                }
            });
        });

        $('.ajax-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var postData = $(this).serialize();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');

            $.ajax({

                url: url,
                data: postData,
                type: $(this).val('method'),
                success: function (data) { //we want to see this data as result it will appeare as result

                    if (!data.error) {

                        $('#lecture-result').html(data); //data from above
                    }
                }
```

**PHP**

```
    namespace Database\Controller; 
    include_once '../Service/DbConfig.php';

    use Database\Service\DbConfig as DbConfig;
    use Database\Entity\Course as Course;

    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if ($action == 'create') {
        createCourse($_POST['title']);
        getCourseListAsView();

    }
    if ($action == 'delete') {
        deleteCourse();

    }

    function deleteCourse () {           

    $query = "DELETE FROM courses WHERE id";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if(isset($result)) {
       echo "YES";
    } else {
       echo "NO";
    }
```

Comment: You have half a query: "DELETE FROM courses WHERE id", you need to specify what ID to delete, e.g. "DELETE FROM courses WHERE id = 1"

Comment: please refer this link https://codewithawa.com/posts/php-crud-create,-edit,-update-and-delete-posts-with-mysql-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DELETE query is not right.

**Delete Query:**

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column = some_value
```

You need to assign id value for delete that row.

```
DELETE FROM courses WHERE id = 3
```

The id value is the id of the row that you want to delete.

Comment: It doesn't look in his code that he has a reference to an id, it might be a good idea to elaborate on how he might get access to the id of the row at this point in his code.